# Widgets not showing on sidebars

Tags: themes, widgets, page-template, sidebar, dashboard

I have registered two sidebars in my theme using the function below, but none of the widgets shows up in the sidebars even though I can manage them in the dashboard:

```
// register sidebars
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_register_sidebars' );
function my_register_sidebars() {

    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'id' => 'sidebar-left',
            'name' => __( 'sidebar-left' ),
            'description' => __( 'A short description of the sidebar.' ),
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h2 class="sidebar-title">',
            'after_title' => '</h2>'
        )
    );

        register_sidebar(
        array(
            'id' => 'sidebar-right',
            'name' => __( 'sidebar-right' ),
            'description' => __( 'A short description of the sidebar.' ),
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h2 class="sidebar-title">',
            'after_title' => '</h2>'
        )
    );
}
```

and to call template file is like this

```
<div id="sidebar-left" >

    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'left' ) ) : ?>

        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'left' ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <p> here should be a left sidebar</p>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

The paragraph shows up but the widgets do not.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the sidebars in your theme? Right now you're just registering them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've registered your sidebars with the `id`s of `sidebar-left` and `sidebar-right` but you are are attempting to display them using only `left` and `right`. You need to use the correct `id`s. That is:

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' );
```

You need that `id` with both `dynamic_sidebar()` and `is_active_sidebar()`

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' ) ) {
  dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' );
} else { ?>
  <p> here should be a left sidebar</p><?php 
}
```

Comment: I wanted to say thanks that solved it 
you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @Yassinz If this answer solved the problme please mark it as "Accepted". Look for the check mark at the top left under the vote arrows.